# jQuery Validation Plugin this.optional is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I create a custom validation. In the docs I found method [addMethod()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

My example:

```
Template.Login.onRendered(() => {
  jQuery.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', (value, element) => {
    return this.optional(element)
      || value.length >= 6
      && /\d/.test(value)
      && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
  }, 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long and contain at least one number and one char.');

$('.login-form').validate({
    rules: {
      password: {
        required: true,
        strongPassword: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And I get error:

> _this.optional is not a function.  Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'strongPassword' method.

That is my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to `this`. When you use arrow functions (you have 2 cases there) the `this` refers to the upper one's div context, in your case is the `this` where `onRendered` has been called. Change `arrow function` into simple function to get the appropriate `this` context.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element)
      || value.length >= 6
      && /\d/.test(value)
      && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
  }, 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long and contain at least one number and one char.');
```

Comment: $(...).optional is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I recently ran into this issue after converting code to ES6.

Standard:

```
this.optional(element)
```

ES6:

```
$.validator.prototype.optional(element)
```

Comment: The accepted answer is true, but this answer is true and correct.

Comment: The answer does work, but it's still a mystery for me and I could not find information about ES6 and this specific case. So could anyone or maybe Rylee, provide me with information why it works?

Comment: @xdevx32 The `optional` property is a standard method on the `validator` class. It doesn't seem to be instance specific (i.e. not using `this` within it) so we can just call the default method on the prototype of `jQuery.validator` and pass in our element as the parameter